# Using form values, how can I load a different page, corresponding to the value submitted?

Tags: javascript, html

When my form is submitted there is a javascript function that is run. The function is as follows:

```js
function userpass(form) 
{
    if (form.id.value == "username") { 
        if (form.pass.value == "password") {              
            location = "nextpage1.php";
        }
    } 
    else {  
        alert("Incorrect Username/Password Combination");
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to use multiple "login" information to load a different page depending on the username/password combination entered. So if instead someone had entered "username2" and the associated password, it would load "nextpage2.php", for example.

This is, I would assume, clearly wrong, but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around javascript. Here is something along the lines of what I have tried:

```js
function userpass(form) 
{
    if (form.id.value == "username") { 
        if (form.pass.value == password") {              
            location = "nextpage1.php";
        } 
    }
    if (form.id.value == "username2") { 
        if (form.pass.value == password2") {              
            location = "nextpage2.php";
        } 
    } 
    else {
        alert("Incorrect Username/Password Combination");
    }
}
```

If anyone can point me in the proper direction, I would be pleased. I am still in the middle of some tutorials on the subject and know I need to learn a lot more, so that kind of feedback is not really necessary.

If you just give a solution on how to do this, I would appreciate an explanation into why it works, rather than to be just shown, this is how it's done.

Comment: I'd like to add, that I am aware that this is not the proper way to do a login system and certainly not in any way, shape, or form, secure. - This is a design project, and the background workings of this are not being used in any real websites or other programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, not a secure way of logging on, but hey-ho, ill answer it as a generic javascript question!

Have you considered using a switch statement? Obviously this wont be very useful for many login options, but for < 10 it could be used?

something like:

```
<script>
function myFunction(form)
{
var user = form.id.value
switch (user)
{

case "username1":
  if (form.pass.value==password1") {  
    location="nextpage1.php";
    }
  break;
case "username2":
  if (form.pass.value==password2") {  
    location="nextpage2.php";
    }
  break;

default:
  //code to be executed if no username matches
  break;

}
</script>
```

Depending on which username is entered the corresponding code for that `case` will run, and if none of the cases are satisfied, `default` will run.

Comment: I am not able to get your code to work for me. I've defined a second var as: var pass = form.pass.value and then proceeded to change the if statement to: if (pass=="password1"). that seems to pass fine, but I get an Unexpected Token error in regards to the case name. I looked further into switches and their syntax, and do not immediately see anything wrong with the code. I've tried instead putting the case name in quotations, but with no change.    -   Otherwise, this piece of code looks like it would work perfectly for what I need it for, only 5 login pages to load. Thanks

Comment: in my haste to write i forgot the 'breaks' in the cases! also the strings need the speechmarks around them, see edit! :)

Comment: I ended up getting this working, I would just like to add that you had no {} curly brackets around the switch body, I've not used a switch statement before and it wasn't immediately obvious that this was what was wrong with the code to me. Thanks for showing me this method though.

Comment: ha apologies - its late...!